# WCF Service with Shared Hoster causes 404 (Placed in IIS App)

Tags: jquery, wcf, iis-7, http-post, wcf-configuration

If I try to hit a method using jQuery or via browser, I get a 404. My configuration looks like the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RegistrationBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RegistrationEndpointBehavior">
                <enableWebScript/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service name="Corp.EmployeeService" behaviorConfiguration="RegistrationBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Corp.IEmployeeService" behaviorConfiguration="RegistrationEndpointBehavior" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I believe it has something to do with the configuration as my method is decorated with an OperationContract and a WebInvoke attribute.

My interface (simplified for posting) looks similar to the following:

```
namespace Corp
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IEmployeeService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
        int Register(string username);
    }
}
```

On the service class itself, I have decorated it with the following attribute:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
```

As I stated, I've tried hitting the service using http://localhost/EmployeeService.svc/Register or using jQuery like so:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost/EmployeeService.svc/Register",
    data: '{"username":"test"}',
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    success: function (msg) {
        var status = msg.RegisterResult;
        if (status == 1) {
            alert('Success');
        } else {
            alert('Failure');
        }
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert('Exception - ' + msg);
    }
});
```

Both return 404's.

Since I'm hosting this service with a shared hosting company, I've created my on ServiceFactory as shown below:

```
public class IisServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        var newAddress = baseAddresses[0];

        if (!newAddress.AbsoluteUri.Contains("http://www."))
            newAddress = new Uri(newAddress.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "http://www."));

        var webServiceHost = new IisServiceHost(serviceType, newAddress);
        return webServiceHost;
    }
}

public class IisServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    public IisServiceHost(Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses): base(serviceType, baseAddresses) { }
}
```

A POST is occurring when trying to hit it from jQuery. The 404 response (from a different sample service that was simplified for testing) is shown below:

[image: 404 Response from another service in the same project]

The text for this exception is: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: You have `Corp.EmployeeServiceService` as the contract - shouldn't that be something like `Corp.EmployeeService.IService`?

Comment: Can you try to remove the BodyStyle and let it take the default value. Also in your RegistrationEndpointBehavior just have enablewebscript rather than having both webhttp and enablewebscript

Comment: Is your service hosting on IIS? Try using Fiddler to perform a POST on the service to see what happens?

Comment: It is on IIS. I've tried creating a custom service host factory. It is doing a Post. I'll update the post above to show the full 404 error.

Comment: The latest is that I can hit the .svc just fine, but I cannot hit the methods. Still getting 404's.

Comment: Still haven't been able to resolve this.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I am facing exactly same issue.

Comment: No I did not. I had to abandon it and go a different route due to time constraints.